# Special character in a pattern angular formController

Tags: javascript, angular, form-control

Like in the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-control-uajxxq)

I have a form control with a pattern validation

```
  formController = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,')]);
```

In the HTML, I have

```
<div [innerHTML]="'Write : ^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,'"></div>
<form>
      <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="formController" autocomplete="off" placeholder="^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,">
        <div *ngIf="formController.hasError('required')">
            POPUP.DELETE_CONFIRMATION_UNMATCHED_REQUIRED
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="formController.hasError('pattern')">
            POPUP.DELETE_CONFIRMATION_UNMATCHED_PATTERN
        </div>
</form>
```

The problem is, the pattern is never matched.

In the exemple, the pattern in static, but in my app, the pattern is the name of a field, and it can contain any characters.

The formControl do not work only when the pattern include special character, it works ok for any other name.

How can I fix it ?

EDIT : The thing is, this is for a deletion confirmation like in github repo.

When you delete the thing, you have to type exactly the name of the repo.

In the app, name can include special character so, if the name of the repo is `^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,'` then I need to type hexactly `^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,'` and nothing else, if the name is `myProject1` only `myProject1` will work

Comment: It is not cleared what you sick for ? you want to allow this symbols? this complete string ? add example of what you write in input and what you expect to see ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your expression is looking for something like

> , &,, , , , -, {, }, ,, <, >,

instead of a special character. All you need is to change is your regex expression to something like:

```
formController = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/)]);
```

Comment: The thing is, this is for a deletion confirmation like in github repo.

When you delete the thing, you have to type exactly the name of the repo.

In the app, name can include special character so, if the name of the repo is ` ^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,'` then I need to type hexactly ` ^, &, *, (, ), +, -, {, }, [, ], <, >,'` and nothing else, if the name is `myProject1` only `myProject1` will work

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code, correct regular expression format implemented

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('hello') hello: NgControl;

  formController = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^([,:\\+\-<>{}&*^()\\[\\]/-]*)$')]);

  name = 'Angular 5';
}
```